# Deleting/Editing fields with Migration Tool

Tags: migration-tool

I'm starting to use ANT to deploy changes to my SF org.
Can I delete and edit custom fields using the ANT Migration Tool.
In the documentation I only found how to delete the entire object

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can specify individual fields in the package.xml (for deploy) and destructivechanges.xml (for deletion)

The syntax is as follows

```
<types>
<members>My_Custom_Object__c.My_Custom_Field__c</members>
<name>CustomField</name>
</types>
```

A great reference for finding the different types you can deploy, and more about the migration tool in general, is http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf